# Send "410 Gone" response for URLs that are a "c" or "g" followed by digits

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, 410-gone

Is there anything i can use in my htaccess to send 410 code to all the links but not some links ?

Example:

I would like to 410 this urls (List is about 40k links)

```
www.example.com/c1
www.example.com/c2
www.example.com/c3
www.example.com/c4
www.example.com/g1
www.example.com/g2
www.example.com/g3
www.example.com/g4
and so one....
```

but this links should not come 410, anything that start with `c` or `g`

Like:

```
www.example.com/categories/
www.example.com/concreate/
www.example.com/colombs/
```

Right now I am using this code in my `.htaccess` file but this also giving 410 to above links.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c
RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c
> ```

Not sure why you are referencing the `QUERY_STRING` here? Your URLs don't appear to contain a query string?

It looks like the URLs you want to block start with a `c` or `g` and followed by a digit (I'll assume 1 or more digits). In which case, try something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[cg]\d+$ - [G]
```

No need for the `L` flag with `G`.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly i was looking for from long time. I just had to add this at the bottom for perfect 410 page "ErrorDocument 410 default". You are just wonderful. Huge thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

user82217 provided a fine solution using mod_rewrite.   You can also use [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) to do it:

```
RedirectMatch gone "/[cg]\d+$"
```