# .htaccess redirect to "410 Gone" status for URLs containg one letter + word "shop" after domain

Tags: htaccess, apache, apache2, 410-gone

After I recovered Drupal 7 site from malware attack I end up with lot of links pointing to (previously) spam content like this:

```
https://www.example.com/lshop/puma-rihanna-c-449/?zenid=id311p8tc67mbnbu8gb17d1uf1
https://www.example.com/eshop/nike-start-l-259/
https://www.example.com/eshop
https://www.example.com/fshop/adidas-maradona-k-149/
```

Content was removed but backlinks left. I was able to compose this rules in `.htaccess` redirecting malicious backlinks to `410 Gone` status page:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
redirect 410 /ashop/
redirect 410 /ashop

redirect 410 /bshop/
redirect 410 /bshop

redirect 410 /cshop/
redirect 410 /cshop

redirect 410 /eshop/
redirect 410 /eshop

redirect 410 /fshop/
redirect 410 /fshop

redirect 410 /ishop/
redirect 410 /ishop

redirect 410 /lshop/
redirect 410 /lshop

redirect 410 /oshop/
redirect 410 /oshop

redirect 410 /pshop/
redirect 410 /pshop
</IfModule>
```

List can be longer. How to catch - using regex - pattern "**backslash after domain + one letter + word 'shop' optionally continuing with backslash**" and redirect such link to `410` on server level befor it touch Drupal?

I tried following patterns based on [these](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106401/send-410-gone-response-for-urls-that-are-a-c-or-g-followed-by-digits) [two](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113455/how-can-i-make-a-specific-series-of-urls-have-410-gone-status) answers but without success:

```
redirect 410 /[a-z]shop/
redirect 410 /^([a-zA-Z])shop/
redirect 410 ^\/([a-z])(shop)\/(.*)$
redirect 410 ^[a-z]shop+$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` is a mod_alias directive (not mod_rewrite) and does not accept a regex. Both the answers you link to use the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive.

Note that in `.htaccess` the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not match against the slash at the start of the URL-path (unlike a mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directive).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]shop($|/) - [G]
```

The above matches either a request for `/xshop` or `/xshop/<anything>` (where `x` is any lowercase letter) and serves a 410 Gone.

This needs to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file and the `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.

Comment: So I have been mixing 2 things. RewriteRule works. Thank you for help @MrWhite